# Keyword search with field level boosting and spatial search

Tags: solr, boosting

Sitecore 9.3

I want to boost a result based on a field containing a keyword and it's working absolutely fine with the below query.

```
var keywordQuery = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
keywordQuery = keywordQuery.Or(item => item.ShortTitle.Contains(keyword)).Boost(5);
keywordQuery = keywordQuery.Or(item => item.LongTitle.Contains(keyword)).Boost(4);
```

Now, along with field boosting, I also need to get the result based on lat/long provided with the query. Having said that, if there are two records with the same boost value or score, the nearest record should come first.

I have added below lines with this query, but I think, it's not working.

```
var queryable = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(query);
queryable = queryable.OrderByDistance(s => s.MyCoordinates, new Coordinate(lat, lng));
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you make sure the template you are using – to store coordinates, inherit from /sitecore/templates/System/Geospatial/Coordinate? and return type for the "MyCoordinates" field is "coordinate" in the config?

Comment: Yes. it is the same and working individually when no boosting is there. But with field boosting, it is not working.